# -- Margin-left: auto; Margin-right: auto; -- or display: inline-block?

Tags: html, margin, css

I have a container and there is a 980px wide div in it.
Which is the more compatible, if i use margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto on the 980px div or if i give a text-align: center to the container and display: inline-block to the 980px div?

Thanks for answers!

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    <!---content here.... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

css v1:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 980px;
}
```

css v2:

```
.content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 980px;
}
```

So what is the most "compatible" for browsers, or what is the best practise to do it?

Comment: It depends on your specific application. Please provide the relevant code (and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), if possible). From the sound of it, I recommend using `margin:0 auto;`.

Comment: More compatible with what?

Comment: Usually the most used and "kind of standard" to center a div in that situation is to use margin auto for the left and right margins.

Comment: using `inline-block` for your entire page container is a bit weird.  even ie6 supports auto margins, iirc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to go with `margin: auto` and not to override the default `display` values of the elements unless it's *really* necessary.

Converting block box into inline-block box will move it from the usual [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) into [inline formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting), and it may cause side effects like vertical gaps due to baseline and `line-height` of the parent element's font, displaying inter-tag line breaks as space characters, etc.